# How to pass temporary granted ContentProvider permissions to Service?

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

I wrote an Activity which need to be able to receive files shared from third party apps. The activity itself got a Service, which need to be able to read these files. I've defined an *intent-filter* for the activity. I read the URI from the first intent coming from the third party app and forward the URI to my Service via my "workintent".

The problem is that I get a SecurityException when trying to read the file in my Service :

`java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.whatsapp.MediaProvider uri content://com.whatsapp.provider.media/item/397213 from pid=16463, uid=10337 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()`

Reading the file in my activity works fine. So I guess the third party content provider grants temporary read permission to my Activity as [described here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html#gprmsn), but this permission isn't valid for my Service because a Service is a different *application component*.

Is there a way to pass the temporary granted permission from the third party app for my activity to my service?

I'm already using these flags for my Service but this didn't work
`workIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);`

this is the full diagram of what's happening in my desired use case:
[image: this is the full diagram of what's happening in my desired use case]

Comment: "I'm already using these flags for my Service but this didn't work " -- I suggest that you edit the question and provide a full [mcve], as that definitely works.